# Foreign key from table to aspnet_Users : ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures, foreign-keys

I have an Employee table which holds a column User_Id of type uniqueidentifier which is a foreign key to the User_Id column in aspnet_Users. When I try to enter a new employee with a sproc by using User.Identity as the param, it gives me this error:

> No mapping exists from object type
>   System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity to a known managed provider
>   native type.

How can I resolve this issue? Relating the registered User and Employee data is necessary, because I need to be able to retrieve only Employee data for the logged in User.

Answer (score 0):

The [IIdentity interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iidentity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is going to give you AuthenticationType, IsAuthenticated, and Name properties.  I don't think those are going to fit into a uniqueidentifier GUID field.  You could try getting User.Identity.Name and putting that into a plain varchar field.  Would that work for your purpose?